# Thumbnail generation in NodeJS with LWIP

Tags: javascript, node.js, lwip

I'm working on a photography social media website and I'm generating thumbnails for each image. The images are displayed at a decent size on the page so the quality can't be decreased too much (e.g. www.prsmphoto.com/user/tyler).

Currently I'm using this:
image.scale(.15);

Which does a decent job of lowering the size of the file. However, this destroys the quality of smaller images which looks horrible. How should I approach this? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sharp or canvas module.

First of all, they are 6-8 times faster than lwip: https://github.com/ivanoff/images-manipulation-performance

Then, you can save file with quality you want:

```javascript
var stream = canvas.jpegStream({
  quality: 80 // JPEG quality (0-100) default: 75
});
```

```javascript
sharp('input.png')
  .rotate(180)
  .resize(300)
  .flatten()
  .background('#ff6600')
  .overlayWith('overlay.png', { gravity: sharp.gravity.southeast } )
  .sharpen()
  .withMetadata()
  .quality(90)
  .webp()
  .toBuffer()
  .then(function(outputBuffer) {
    // outputBuffer contains upside down, 300px wide, alpha channel flattened
    // onto orange background, composited with overlay.png with SE gravity,
    // sharpened, with metadata, 90% quality WebP image data. Phew!
  });
```